# userSchema.plugin is not a function

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, passport-local-mongoose

I installed `passport-local-mongoose` package and when I used this:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const plm = require("passport-local-mongoose");

mongoose.connect(
  `mongodb+srv://Funn:000000@cluster0.q3gng0d.mongodb.net/`, 
   {
    dbName: "Auth"
   }

).then((c) => console.log("db connected",c.connection.host))
  .catch((e) => console.log(e));
  
   const userSchema = {
   username: String,
   password: String,
   secret:String,
  }


userSchema.plugin(plm);// because of this line it throw error 

module.exports = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);
```

It throws an error:

```
userSchema.plugin is not a function
```

Comment: What's the version of mongoose?

Comment: `userSchema` is just an object you have defined.

Answer (score 0):

The error is becuase `userSchema` is just a [POJO](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/pojo) so it doesn't have any mongoose methods inherited.

You need to create a new instance of the mongoose Schema like so:

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   username: String,
   password: String,
   secret:String,
});
userSchema.plugin(plm);
```

Comment: thankyou so much bro it resolves my problem ,

Comment: @Harish__ you're welcome.